# How to map custom report ts file from node library in playwright.config.ts?

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright, end-to-end, playwright-test

I came across custom report feature in Playwright(node js). I would like to use the custom-reporter.ts class from the external node library installed.
Please help me to know, How to map that file in Playwright.config.ts?

```
   (playwright.config.ts) 
        config = {
           reporter: './node_modules/mylibrary/report/lib/my-reporter'
        }
    It works, but i am not sure whether this approach is adviceable or not.
```